# Decorator to validate that Python function arguments are positive

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, meta-programming

I have a list of functions whose parameters in the signature should be validated with the same criteria each time.

```py
def sum_first_positive(a=1,b=1,c=1):
    assert a > 0
    return a + b + c

def sum_second_positive(a=1,b=1,c=1):
    assert b > 0
    return a + b + c

def sum_third_positive(a=1,b=1,c=1):
    assert c > 0
    return a + b + c


def sum_all_positives(a=1,b=1,c=1):
    assert a > 0
    assert b > 0
    assert c > 0
    return a + b + c
```

Rather than copy pasting the same validator inside each function, I want to use a decorator instead.

Here is my (working) attempt:

```py
def decorator(*decorator_arguments):
    def inner_decorator(function):
        def wrapper(**kwargs):
            for val in decorator_arguments:
                if kwargs[val] <= 0:
                    raise ValueError(f"Value '{val}' should be strictly positive. You passed {kwargs[val]}")
            
            return function(**kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return inner_decorator


@decorator("c")
def sum_third_positive(a=0, b=0, c=1):
    return a + b + c


@decorator("a", "b", "c")
def sum_all_positives(a=0, b=0, c=0):
    return a + b + c

# Fails
sum_all_positives(a=-1,b=1,c=1)

# OK
sum_third_positive(a=-1,b=1,c=10)

# Fails
sum_third_positive(a=-1,b=1,c=-10)
```

The problem is, the user will have to pass all the arguments by name as I can not pass positional arguments to the wrapper.

I can define the function as:

```
@decorator("c")
def sum_third_positive(*, a=0, b=0, c=1):
    return a + b + c
```

to not allow for positional arguments, but this is not ideal.

Is there a solution to pass positional arguments, by position to the decorator arguments and check on their values?

Comment: You may be interested in [my fairly comprehensive untyped decorator answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/256424). If you don't want to spend 20 minutes reading a wall of text [your answer is just inspect.signature](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/272072).

Answer (score 2):

**The user-facing name should be substantive**. Give it a name to convey its
behavior or purpose: `require_positive_params()` in the illustration below. On
a more technical level, the user-facing function is not exactly a decorator so
much as it is a decorator factory: it returns the actual decorator that
replaces the original function. Similar thoughts can be applied to
`decorator_arguments`.

**The error message can convey the parameter name**. It's more helpful to the
reader and not a difficult change.

**Use functools.wraps()**. It's easy and useful.

**Use inspect.signature() to support positionals from callers**. Requires only
a small addition.

```
from functools import wraps
from inspect import signature

def require_positive_params(*param_names):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*xs, **kws):
            params = signature(func).bind(*xs, **kws).arguments
            for p in param_names:
                val = params[p]
                if val <= 0:
                    msg = f'Parameter should be positive: got {p}={val}'
                    raise ValueError(msg)
            return func(*xs, **kws)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

**Next step: consider pulling the validation behavior out of the decorator**.
It's not too difficult to support a usage pattern like the one sketched below.

```
def require(validator, *param_names):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        ...

def is_positive(name, val):
    if val > 0:
        return True
    else:
        msg = f'Parameter should be positive: got {name}={val}'
        raise ValueError(msg)

def is_even(name, val):
    ...

@require(is_positive, 'c')
def sum1(a, b, c = 99):
    return a + b + c

@require(is_even, 'a', 'b')
def sum2(a, b = 0, c = 0):
    return a + b + c
```

Answer (score 1):

I am against decorators or partial wrappers and recommend [type hints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72563242/3515670) to restrict the expected types' values.

This way, a source code checker with a reasonable type hinting feature can detect issues regarding the type constraints already while programming instead of during runtime.
Since you speak of *the user*, I suspect your (pseudo) code is part of a library intended for use by others.
When using such a library, I'd prefer that the IDE already detects such an issue instead of the unit tests.

**NB**: In your case you want to use `Ge` instead of `Gt`.

Answer (score -1):

The decorator approach seems somewhat over-engineered and I am going to recommend against it. Consider a simple `partial`:

```py
from functools import partial


def check_and_sum(positive_idx: tuple[int, ...], a: int = 1, b: int = 1, c: int = 1) -> int:
    addends = a, b, c
    for idx in positive_idx:
        val = addends[idx]
        if val < 1:
            raise ValueError(f'Addend {idx} with value {val} must be at least 1')

    return sum(addends)


sum_first_positive = partial(check_and_sum, (0,))
sum_second_positive = partial(check_and_sum, (1,))
sum_third_positive = partial(check_and_sum, (2,))
sum_all_positive = partial(check_and_sum, (0, 1, 2))
```

Tested as:

```py
def test() -> None:
    assert sum_first_positive(1, 2, -3) == 0
    assert sum_second_positive(1, 2, -3) == 0
    assert sum_third_positive(1, -2, 3) == 2
    assert sum_third_positive(1, -2) == 0
    assert sum_all_positive(1, 2, 3) == 6

    try:
        sum_first_positive(0, 2, 3)
        raise AssertionError()
    except ValueError:
        pass

    try:
        sum_second_positive(1, 0, 2)
        raise AssertionError()
    except ValueError:
        pass

    try:
        sum_third_positive(1, 2, 0)
        raise AssertionError()
    except ValueError:
        pass

    for bad_index in range(3):
        addends = list(range(1, 4))
        addends[bad_index] = 0
        try:
            sum_all_positive(*addends)
            raise AssertionError()
        except ValueError:
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: "The decorator approach seems somewhat over-engineered and I am going to recommend against it." And you recommend a closure which doesn't fit in the decorator pattern in a decoratoresque pattern? I think your psudo-decorator is far worse than a simple decorator.